# how to load data from s3 to elastic search using java lambda

Tags: java, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to create a lambda function in java which will trigger when ever a object is created in amazon s3 and will push the data into elastic search.

Could any of you please point me to a code or post that handles this use case in Java?